# Set persistence for user in firebase authentication (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hi i am quite new to kotlin programming, still a student in degree and now im trying to create some sort of persistence where the user is able to auto log in when they enter the app with the condition that the content in my user shared preference is not empty(where i store my user ID)

I dont quite understand how firebase authentication token work as a whole and how to somehow set some sort of persistence for the user after they log in the first time or is it just not possible with kotlin because i am aware that firebase admin you are somehow able to set some sort of refresh tokens

so i am in need of some knowledge about this and maybe some expert opinion on what im trying to achieve is feasible or not. Thank you in advance

tried signInWithCustomToken() but i dont understand how to create a proper format of custom tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sign in with the Firebase SDK, it automatically persist the credentials to local storage on the device. When the user restarts the app, the Firebase SDK automatically reads those credentials and tries to restore the user's sign-in state.

You can listen to that restore process and other state changes as shown in: [Listen for authentication state in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android). You don't need custom tokens for that, so I'd recommend using one of the built-in providers.

Comment: I was wondering how long does the credentials last for?